# Is explicit transaction creation required for database reads when using JpaTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

In our application we mainly use Spring @Transactional annotations together with JpaTemplate and Hibernate for database interaction.  One part of the project, however, communicates with a different database, and hence we cannot use @Transactional here as a different transactionManager is required.

Here, for database updates, we explicitly create transactions in code, using PlatformTransactionManager, and either commit them or roll back after the call to JpaTemplate.execute(JpaCallback).

I have noticed a few places in this area of our code where we are not doing this for reads, however, and simply call JpaTemplate.execute(JpaCallback) without wrapping in a transaction.  I am wondering what the dangers are of this.  I appreciate that a transaction must be being created, as no database query can be run without a transaction, but since nothing in our code attempts to commit, will something potentially be holding on to resources?

Comment: Do note that you can have multiple transaction managers to which you refer to in the @Transactional declaration (the value attribute).

Comment: Oh yes thanks - I think this was introduced in Spring 3.0.  A lot of the code was written a few years ago and we were using Spring 2.  We have since upgraded to Spring 3 so that may be the way to go.  Presumably the name of the transaction manager specified in the value attribute overrides the one specified by <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"/>?  I'd still be interested to know if there are any dangers associated with not declaring transactions for reads.